# Extract 7z SFX files using C#

Tags: .net, extract, exe, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I have an exe file of type 7z SFX. A text file is compressed inside the exe file. How can I read the contents of text file inside exe in C#. I tried extracting using sevenzipsharp library but got an exception `End of central directory record could not found`.